# What is an English word for “something that adds value”?

Tags: word-choice

I’m looking for an English word which could mean *something or someone that adds value to something else*. Is there a single word for that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That will depend on how you define *value*. A [contribution](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/contribution) can be considered as *something that adds value*. An [enrichment](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/enrichment?showCookiePolicy=true) can also be considered as *something that adds value*.

Comment: +1 Good answer.  You could add enhancement and improvement to this list as well.

Comment: If it is a person, which word is better. In your answer `contribution` is a good choice for work, project verbs. `enrichment` is good for objects. similarly, what is the best choice for a person?

Answer (score 3):

Would 'enhances' be the word you are looking for? 'The large shirt I am wearing enhances my appearance, as it hides the roll of fat across my middle'.

Answer (score 2):

**Enhancer** or **Enhancement**

From the word *[enhance](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/enhancer)*: to make greater, as in value, beauty, or effectiveness; augment; to provide with improved, advanced, or sophisticated features.

This would satisfy the request for a word that applies to something that adds value to something else. But I don't think I've heard it used to apply to a person who adds to the value of something.

Answer (score 0):

What of [Asset](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/asset) which is a currency exchance for value?